# React context updates in parent component, but for child components it's still undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a problem with useContext in React. I want to update it in my parent component, then use it in child components. However, while the context seem to work properly inside my parent component, when I want to use it in the children, it's undefined (still has its default value).

The code snippets that illustrate the problem:

**LobbyContext.tsx**

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from "react";
import { ILobby } from "@/components/GameIndex";

interface ILobbyContext {
    lobby: ILobby | undefined;
    setLobby: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ILobby | undefined>>;
}

export const LobbyContext = createContext<ILobbyContext>({
    lobby: "",
    setLobby: () => {
        console.log("old function")}
});

export function LobbyProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [lobby, setLobby] = useState<ILobby | undefined>();

    return (
        <LobbyContext.Provider value={{ lobby, setLobby }}>
            {children}
        </LobbyContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**/game/[id].tsx**

```
import {LobbyProvider} from "@/context/LobbyContext";
import GameIndex from "@/components/GameIndex"
const Index = () => {

    return (
            <LobbyProvider>
                <GameIndex />
            </LobbyProvider>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

fragments of **GameIndex.tsx**

```
const { lobby, setLobby } = useContext(LobbyContext);

/*...*/

useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/lobby/${lobbyId}`)
        .then(data => {
            setLobby(data);
        }
, [lobby, setLobby] }

/*...*/

    return (
       {lobby !== undefined ? <Scoreboard/> : <div>Loading...</div>}
    );
```

**Scoreboard.tsx**

```
import {LobbyContext} from "@/context/LobbyContext";

const Scoreboard = () => {
    const {lobby, setLobby} = useContext(LobbyContext);

return (
        <div className={"scoreboard flex-col"}>
        {lobby}
        </div>
    );
}
```

ironically, Scoreboard renders, because `lobby` is defined inside of GameIndex.tsx, but inside of Scoreboard, it's undefined...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue - it turns I have used ContextProvider twice - both in /game/[id].tsx and GameIndex.tsx. By removing the GameIndex provider, the context now works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

When processing the fetch request, you should parse the retrieved data as JSON and pass this processed data to the setLobby function.
Update the default value type in the LobbyContext to ILobby.
Within the useEffect hook, specify the dependencies of the fetch request. In this case, include the lobbyId dependency.
By making these adjustments, the lobby variable in the Scoreboard component should no longer be undefined and should receive the correct value.

Comment: It still just doesn't update...

Comment: it's as if the setter was working locally, but it just doesn't update the global context